# What's the difference between Go and Javascript about 0xFFFFFFFF ^ 97

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, math

I want to change Go code to Javascript code, but there is one mistake about result that is different between Go and Javascript.
I want to change javascript's result to same as Go's result (0xFFFFFFFF ^ 97)

I try to debug it, and I recognize that 0xFFFFFFFF ^ 97 , in Go is 4294967198 but in javascript it is -98.

In Go:

```
number1 := 0xFFFFFFFF
number2 := 97
fmt.Print(number1 ^ number2) // 4294967198
```

In Javascript:

```
var number1 = 0xFFFFFFFF
var number2 = 97
console.log(number1 ^ number2) // -98
```

0xFFFFFFFF ^ 97 is different result in Go and Javascript

Comment: bitwise operations in javascript result in signed 32 bit result - as per **[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers)**

Comment: When you use *any* of the bitwise operators in JavaScript, the number you operate on is first converted to a 32-bit **signed** integer, then the operation is performed, then it's converted back to a double (an IEEE-754 binary double-precison number). I can't speak for GoLang, but my guess is you're dealing with unsigned there instead.

Comment: The Go version uses the `int` type which is `int64` or `int32` depending on the architecture. Since you get a result and not a compile-time overflow, it's `int64`.

Comment: just add `0x100000000` if the result is negative in javascript

Comment: As @JaromandaX wrote, use `console.log(0x100000000+(number1 ^ number2))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, a bitwise operation (`^` is bitwise XOR) converts the numbers signed 32-bit integer, then back to a double. So after the XOR operation is performed, the number is converted back to its default type - IEEE-754 double-precision binary number - and then the result is given.

```
number -> 32-bit signed integer -> bitwise operation -> IEEE-754 double-precision binary number
```

GoLang uses unsigned integers ([GoLang spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)), or, as pointed out by [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza), `int64` numbers.

Comment: Go doesn't use unsigned integers in the above code, but `int64`.

Comment: Thanks @icza, I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Also include the "fix" how to get the same output as in Go and it'll be perfect.

Comment: There is no real "fix" unless you recreate bitwise XOR with IEEE-754.